# jquery overlay hide on second click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a webpage with a number of images.
On desktop when I mouseover I have an overlay with extra details.

```
<li>
 <div class="pic">
   <div class="overlay  touch">
     <div class="content">extra content here</div>
   </div>
  <img src="image.jpg" alt="" >
 </div>
</li>
```

As the mouseover event doesn't work on mobiles (specifically iOS) I'm using the following script to capture mobile touch and show the overlay:

```
$(".touch").on("mouseenter mouseleave touchstart", function(e){
   if(e.type == 'touchstart') {
     $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
   }
  $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

This all works fine, but now i'd like the overlay to be hidden on a second click on mobiles.

Currently the overlay will hide if another element or a 'blank' space on the page is clicked.

How can i get the overlay to hide on second 'touch' click?

Answer (score 0):

If the device is smaller than 767px, the first click will show the content, the second will hide it.

```
if($(window).width() < 767) {
    $('.touch').click(function() {
        $(this).find('.content').toggle();
    });
}
```

And just make sure that `.content`is `display:none` in your CSS.

Comment: thanks for the comment... i had to apply the click function to the parent LI as the div with the 'touch' style is the overlay (not just the child div)... i have a problem now that the first click does nothing, you have to click twice for the overlay to appear.... any suggestions?